# umask getting sets to 022 even though all necessary files are modified

Tags: shell, centos, umask

`umask` is creating lots of problem to me . 
I tried following .

I have commented umask set entry in */etc/profile* and */etc/bashrc* . There is not even single file in my home direcotry where i set umask .
I have changed UMASK in /etc/login.defs to 011 .
When i log in and run `umask` still it shows me 022 . It should show me as 011 right ?

I am using centos 6.6

Answer (score 1):

The `UMASK` parameter of `/etc/login.defs` is used when you create new users.

For what you're trying to do, editing `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc` is a good idea since those files are usually `source`d by users.

When `umask` is not defined, then it has the default `022`.

Comment: Ohh.. thanks. I am using clish as my shell for one user. But there is not settings for clish to set umask. Now how to handle umask for clish shell ?

Comment: @Niraj Good question... `umask` is usually a shell builtin. I really don't know how to manage it with `clish`, sorry :/ (actually, I've never heard about `clish` before...)